# Sending mail using GCP on private network

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, vpn

More than a simple question-answer, this is more of a recommendation post. Want to see what ideas I have to work with. I am working on porting my company's work to the cloud (GCP) Most of this work is in the form of a pipeline. I'd like to notify completion via email.

The company I work for has a private network. And so the only way to use their mail config is to send it through their internet, and so, cannot use their SMTP-config from GCP.

What's the best way around this?

I'm looking into creating a VPN between GCP and our local network, however, that may not be possible (IT restrictions)

Do I have any other options?

#### EDIT

What an SMTP Relay work? [This](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en) guy.

Comment: You have to use VPN or any other option for private connectivity (https://cloud.google.com/hybrid-connectivity/)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports but port 25,so if you need to [send an email from the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports) you have to use port 465 or 587.

GCP explecitely recomends using other [third-party tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#choosing_an_email_service_to_use) such as SendGrid, Mailgun, and Mailjet because they offer a free tier package, you can skip all that and connect your instance to [Gmail SMTP Relay Service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600). You will need a Google Account to connect (gmail or Gsuite).

Instructions to configure the Google Account are [HERE](https://help.frontapp.com/t/184yz6/configuring-g-suite-accounts-to-send-via-gmail-smtp-relay) , I tested sending emails from my MySQL server and Debian 9

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful post. However, I think you misunderstood. I want to send an email from an instance on GCP but it should go thorugh our (my company's) private SMTP server on-prem. I think the only way around this will be a VPN.